# What does cross platform folder do in Holotoolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am working on a project with hololens.

to accelerate my development I started using Holotoolkit-Unity [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity) from microsoft. One of the folders in assets/holotoolkit is named CrossPlatform. I have a hard time understanding what the folder is for. The Readme says:

> ### CrossPlatform
>
> Wrapper scripts for Win32 and WinRT APIs in a single API call that works in the Unity editor and in a UWP application.

but I am not sure what this actually means. My concern is that I want to get rid of most of the files from holotoolkit-unity that I don't use and only leave the required ones. So I am thinking I need to leave build script and some other features I want to use like (input or spatialmapping), but I don't understand in what case if not in all I would like to keep crossplatform folder.

I also don't understand difference between [Holotoolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit) vs [Holotoolkit-Unity](https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity) repos. is Holotoolkit the bare minimum toolkit that most of the apps will require? is Holotoolkit-Unity the full holotoolkit library that u can choose features from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HoloToolkit is used to interact with the hardware of the HoloLens and is written in C++.  This is what you would want to use if you are writing Direct X code and working directly with the HoloLens.  The HoloToolkit-Unity is a layer on top of the HoloToolkit written in C# that is used to allow easy access to this functionality from Unity.

The Cross Platform libraries are used to make interop calls to Win32 and WinRT methods.  They are designed to allow this to work in both the unity editor and when compiled as a WinRT app.  They are there to handle reflection, exceptions, and pointers for making calls into c++ libraries.  The HoloToolkit is completely written in C++ so these are important to allow the Unity Holotoolkit call into it.  There are a lot of places in the HoloToolkit-Unity where calls are made into HoloToolkit and the cross platform libraries are used for those calls. I would recommend leaving this folder in place if you are using the Unity HoloToolkit.

If you really want to understand where these are used, right before building and deploying in Visual Studio, remove this folder and check out all the compilation errors, this will help you understand what parts of the Unity HoloToolkit use it.